# Socket.io android not connecting it is working fine with web clinet not working in android

Tags: android, nginx, websocket, socket.io

Hello I try to connect android my socket.io to my nodejs server which is hosted using ngnix

this is my android code which i have used in my android app

```
private var mSocket: Socket? = null
val opts = IO.Options()
opts.forceNew = true
opts.reconnection = true
val aara = arrayOf("websocket")
opts.transports = aara

try {
    mSocket = IO.socket(socket_url, opts)
    mSocket?.connect()
    mSocket?.emit("connection", "Nickname");
    mSocket?.emit("user_connect", "Nickname");
    Log.e("mSocket: ", mSocket?.connected().toString())
    mSocket?.on("connection") {
      Log.e("onCreate4w: ", "${it::class.simpleName} ${it.size}")
      Log.e("mSocket: ", mSocket?.connected().toString())
    }
} catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
    Log.e("onCreate25: ", mSocket?.connected().toString())
}
```

and server code is which is written in Nodejs

```
const io = soketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: [
      process.env.TYPEFORM_ORIGIN,
      process.env.ADMINPANEL_ORIGIN,
      
      "http://localhost:4200",
       "*"
      ,
    ],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true,
  },
  multiplex: false,
});
io.on("connection", (soket) => {
    soket.on("user_connect", (userId) => {
      // console.log("USER1", user);
      user[userId] = soket.id;
      // console.log("USER2", user);
      console.log("User Connected", soket.id);
    });
```

and this is ngnix configuration which are enabled in server

```
 location \ {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5555;
    }
```

Please guide us where we doing wrong
this setup is working fine with web pannel, not in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first `mSocket?.connect()` do not return connected socket and you not able to emit immediately. At second you need to subscribe on different socket states to handle errors

```
mSocket!!.on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected") // emit is possible
    }.on("connection") {
        Log.e("onCreate4w: ", "${it::class.simpleName} ${it.size}")
        Log.e("mSocket: ", mSocket?.connected().toString())
    }.on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR) {
        it?.forEach { out ->
            Log.w("EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR", out.toString())
        }
    }.on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT) {
        it?.forEach { out ->
            Log.w("EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT", out.toString())
        }
    }.on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_RECONNECT_ERROR) {
        it?.forEach { out ->
            Log.w("EVENT_RECONNECT_ERROR", out.toString())
        }
    }.on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_RECONNECT_FAILED) {
        it?.forEach { out ->
            Log.w("EVENT_RECONNECT_FAILED", out.toString())
        }
    }.on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING) {
        it?.forEach { out ->
            Log.d("EVENT_CONNECTING", out.toString())
        }
    }
mSocket!!.connect()
```

Comment: Hello Stanislav. Thank you for your response but this approach also not working

Comment: @AmitKumar Logcat doesn't showing any logs ?

Comment: I don't think this is the android issue this is more node issue because the same thing happens in the Ios part

Comment: @AmitKumar Try it with defaults and remove `opts.transports` override

Comment: Hello Stanislav, Thanks for your valuable time. Your code help us get the actual issue causing socket was not getting connected.There is versioning issue in node side. We are using now 2.3.0 version in our backend now my code working fine